# Strange icon on Apple/iOS related tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Today I was looking at iOS and Swift tags on stackoverflow, and noticed a bunch of Apple/iOS related tags have an icon on them that kind of looks like a blurry, cropped facebook logo

[image]

Its not on all of them but is on at least these 3:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/app-store/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swiftystorekit/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/in-app-purchase/info

These have nothing to do with facebook. I don't seem to have permission to edit this as I don't see any options for icons. Can someone remove them? It looks very strange.

Comment: I've seen that icon on a few other tags today, but I can't recall which ones now.

Comment: Facebook likes us ...

Comment: It seems we've turned the Facebook down to normal volumes, so I'm marking this as "completed". Feel free to open another bug report if you see this again on these or any other tags.