# Why does the `double-click` tag have a Facebook icon?

Tags: bug, status-completed, sponsored-tags

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/double-click/info

[image]

If a double click is a practice that predates Facebook why is it associated with that tag? Why is Facebook relevant to this tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's going on with the \[google-roads-api\] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394810/whats-going-on-with-the-google-roads-api-tag)

Comment: @Scratte It kind of does but please don't close this post; it's not a duplicate if it is seen as a bug report. (The tag is different and staff may want to track as such)

Comment: I can't close nor re-open it. I just think all these are collected into one bucket. There's another one too [Strange icon on Apple/iOS related tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394826/strange-icon-on-apple-ios-related-tags)

Comment: The staff use a separate bug tracking system, so no need to worry about closing duplicate bug reports.

Comment: What's going on is "double-click" is also the name of an advertising network.

Comment: @BSMP If you're thinking of doubleclick.net I think that's owned by Google isn't it?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Actually...[we now have a direct path into their internal bug-tracking system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345032/community-and-moderator-guidelines-for-escalating-issues-via-new-response-proces). However, it looks like this has now been fixed, so I'm changing the tag to [[meta-tag:status-completed]].

Comment: @customcommander Yes, but so was the tag in the duplicate. In the comments it was pointed out that the logo had been added to a bunch of ad related tags so I'm guessing that's what happened here: Facebook was added to advertising related tags and double-click was mistaken for doubleclick.net and thus added to that tag as well.